# RxJS creating Observables in a loop

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to create Observables in a loop and wait for them all to be finished.

```
for (let slaveslot of this.fromBusDeletedSlaveslots) {
                    this.patchSlave({
                        Id: slaveslot.Id,
                        BusOrder: null,
                        BusId: null
                    });
                }
```

The patchSlave() Function returns a Observable.

```
patchSlave(slaveslot: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.patch(environment.apiBaseUrl + `/odata/SlaveSlots(${slaveslot.Id})`, slaveslot);
}
```

I don't know the best way to solve this. I think I have to omit the loop a replace a with something from Rxjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use here RxJS `forkJoin` operator.

You can pass array of observables, and it will give final value when all observables are completed.

```
let array = [];
for (let slaveslot of this.fromBusDeletedSlaveslots) {
               array.push ( this.patchSlave({
                        Id: slaveslot.Id,
                        BusOrder: null,
                        BusId: null
                    }));
                }

forkJoin(array).subscribe(results => {console.log(results)});
```

Refer here for more details : [RxJS forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

Comment: Okay thank you very much!! Yeah I though of it. Is there a way without an array?

Comment: Consider using the merge? It's the next item in the provided link.